# Using PHP script to load video tag, working properly on one server but not loading video on one another server

Tags: php, jquery

Using PHP script to load video tag, working properly on one server but not loading video on one another server.

My Code Snippet:

```
<video controls src="demo.mp4"></video>
    <?php

      if (session_id() == '') {
       session_start();
      }
      error_reporting(0);
      $out2 = ob_get_contents();
      if (strpos($out2, "<video") || strpos($out2, "<audio") || strpos($out2, "<source")) {
       ob_clean();
       if (strpos($out2, "<safe") == false) {
        $window = md5(time());
        $_SESSION['window'] = $window;

        ?>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" >
        <script>
         jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/enable.php",
         });
        </script>

        <?php
        if (strpos($out2, "<safe") !== false) {
         $_SESSION['safe'] = "SAFE";
        }

        function getURL($matches) {
         global $rootURL;
         if ($_SESSION['defat'] == "") {
          $_SESSION['defat'] = 1;
         } else {
          $_SESSION['defat'] = $_SESSION['defat'] + 1;
         }
         $_SESSION['x' . $matches['2'] . $_SESSION['defat']] = 0;
         $_SESSION['defa' . $matches['2'] . $_SESSION['defat']] = md5(time() . "Defa Protector");
         $_SESSION['imdefa' . $_SESSION['defat']] = md5('Defa') . base64_encode(base64_encode($matches['2']));
         $_SESSION['x' . $matches['2']] = 0;
         $_SESSION['defa' . $matches['2']] = md5(time() . "Defa Protector");
         $_SESSION['file' . $_SESSION['defat']] = md5('Defa') . base64_encode(base64_encode($matches['2']));
         return $matches[1] . $rootURL . "defavid.php?window=" . $_SESSION['window'] . "&defat=" . $_SESSION['defat'];

        }

        $mes = preg_replace_callback("/(<video[^>]*src *= *[\"']?)([^\"']*)/i", getURL, $out2);
        $mes = preg_replace_callback("/(<source[^>]*src *= *[\"']?)([^\"']*)/i", getURL, $mes);
        $mes = preg_replace_callback("/(<audio[^>]*src *= *[\"']?)([^\"']*)/i", getURL, $mes);
        echo $mes;
       } else {
        echo $out2;
       }
      }

    ?>
```

This script is working properly for one server, but when I put it on one another severe then its not loading to video.

**I tried by commenting ob_clean(); then its working there also. But I dont have to comment that. So please suggest me changes.**

Comment: Did you check your network settings? Maybe a firewall that is blocking you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your not working server is **Apache** it might be a not/misconfigured **.htaccess**

See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: working in codeigniter.. root folder .htaccess is same on both servers